# Does ADFS (as SP) support integration with an OpenID IDP

Tags: openid, openid-connect, adfs, adfs3.0

Does ADFS (as SP) support integration with an "OpenID connect" IDP ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OIDC, you need ADFS 4 or 5 (server 2019).

ADFS only supports OIDC IDP i.e. only OIDC in.

It does not support OIDC out so cannot function as an OIDC SP.

Comment: Ok. So if I want to use AzureAD B2C as IDP (and ADFS as SP), I need to use SAML?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.